# Error on AWS deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on a project that I haven't touched in about 4 months. Before everything on the deploy was working fine, but now I'm getting an error when trying to deploy an update `eb deploy my-env-name`.

> Failed to pull Docker image amazon/aws-eb-python:3.4.2-onbuild-3.5.1:
>   Pulling repository amazon/aws-eb-python time="2016-01-17T01:40:45Z"
>   level="fatal" msg="Could not reach any registry endpoint" . Check
>   snapshot logs for details. Hook
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh failed. For more
>   detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

In the eb-activity log, it further states:

> [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Activity
>   execution failed, because: Pulling repository amazon/aws-eb-python

..before repeating what was shown in the UI.

The original was using a Preconfigured Docker 64bit Debian jessie v1.3.1 running Python 3.4. I've tried upgrading to the latest, which is version 2.0.6, but it never completes (don't need to get into specifics of that error, separate issue and I'd like to stay on 1.3.1 if possible). I've also tried upgrading to the latest 1.x but it has the same result of upgrading to 2.0.6.

Any ideas, or anything else I should be looking for clues?

EDIT: Here is the contents of my Dockerfile, which gets generated automatically

```
FROM amazon/aws-eb-python:3.4.2-onbuild-3.5.1
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile (if not sensitive) ? Also, do you have the same problem if you're testing in local (with Debian/Docker or Windows-Mac/Kitematic) ?

Comment: @DeadEye added Dockerfile in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Dockerfile points out that you are using an image coming from the Docker Hub.
Your Elastic Beanstalk instance is running `Preconfigured Docker 64bit Debian jessie v1.3.1` which is less than 1.6.

Unfortunately, the Docker Hub has deprecated versions earlier than 1.6 since 7 december 2015 : https://blog.docker.com/2015/10/docker-hub-deprecation-1-5/.

You should upgrade your EB/Docker instance to 1.6 minimum.

Comment: hmmm thanks, makes sense. Now I guess I'm back to the question of why I'm not able to upgrade to the newer version of the Preconfigured docker 2.0.6 (which uses docker 1.7.1).

Comment: That's another problem you should develop by including config files, logs and everything else that could be interesting. Someone else seems to have the same problem (http://sha.nnoncarey.com/blog/archives/352), using the EB-CLI seems to be a good workaround.